# How to create QML slider with a custom shape?

Tags: qt, qml

I have to create a slider with a custom shape like the one shown below (blue is the slider handle):

[image]

The red color one is groove and the blue color one is handle.

Comment: What do you mean `random shape`?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah, the wording is inaccurate. I do believe snehitha means a slider with a form that doesn't come as default in QML.

Answer (score 1):

For the groove, you can use any `Item` to draw this shape, e.g. a `Image`
For the handle, you just use a `Rectangle` and place it according to the `Slider.position`, e.g. like so:

```
Slider {
    id: slider
    width: 400
    height: 150
    y: 200
    handle: Rectangle {
        x: slider.leftPadding + slider.visualPosition * (slider.availableWidth - width)
        y: Math.max(slider.topPadding, slider.availableHeight - height + slider.topPadding - ((slider.availableHeight - height) * (slider.position * 2)))
        width: 15
        height: 30
        radius: 5
        color: 'blue'
    }
}
```

If you have a stranger shape, just change the function for y.
You can use any function that maps a value `position` (range [0, 1]) to an y-value. You can use every property of the slider, to calculate an appropriate position.

Here another example, where the slider draws the sine function:

```
Slider {
    width: 400
    height: 150
    id: slider1
    y: 200
    handle: Rectangle {
        x: slider1.leftPadding + slider1.visualPosition * (slider1.availableWidth - width)
        y: slider1.topPadding + (slider1.availableHeight - height) / 2  + (slider1.availableHeight - height) / 2 * Math.sin(slider1.position * 10)
        width: 15
        height: 30
        radius: 5
        color: 'blue'
    }
}
```

And here for the fun of it: A **random** function. But I don't think you can draw a fitting groove to it

```
Slider {
    id: slider
    width: 400
    height: 150
    y: 200
    onPositionChanged: {
        var a = Math.round(Math.random() * 5) - Math.round(Math.random() * 5)
        console.log(a)
        handle.handleY = handle.y + (a)
        console.log(handle.handleY)
    }
    handle: Rectangle {
        property int handleY: slider.topPadding + slider.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
        x: slider.leftPadding + slider.visualPosition * (slider.availableWidth - width)
        y: Math.max(slider.topPadding, Math.min(handleY, slider.availableHeight - height + slider.topPadding))
        width: 15
        height: 30
        radius: 5
        color: 'blue'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in QML using `Canvas` or in Qt C++ ([example with a circular slider](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/custom_control_tutorial.html)) and then expose the element to QML. While not a direct copy-and-paste solution check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22903361/1559401) to see a custom circular progress bar that uses [`arc()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#arc-method) to draw the element. You can use [`line()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#lineTo-method) if you want straight lines. The behaviour of the slider is also something you will have to do on your own.

You can try to inherit from [`Slider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-slider.html) to try and get some (or even most) of the functionality that your element requires.